# error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale with values considered as a factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems to point out specific points that determine a smoothing curves, specifically that ones which have information about "stadio" `as.factor` at 5 levels (values from 1 to 6), all the others points are NA in this column.

```
srt(tab1a)

'data.frame': 870 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mese      : Factor w/ 11 levels "agiu","blug",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sito      : Factor w/ 2 levels "sin","tav": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ area      : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`
 $ staz      : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ classe    : Factor w/ 3 levels "g","m","p": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ taglia    : num  59 62 62 65 68 54 51 58 45 45 ...
 $ p_umido   : num  83.2 97.8 100.2 102.1 130.3 ...
 $ p_umido_go: Factor w/ 563 levels "0.008","0.01",..: 525 558 458 506 485 402 378 521 358 240 ...
 $ igs       : num  8.34 9.49 5.39 6.13 4.49 6.22 6.6 8.16 8.92 5.63 ...
 $ sesso     : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","m": NA 2 2 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ stadio    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","3","4","5",..: NA 4 4 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


plot.tav1 <- qplot(taglia, igs, data=tab1a[1:84,  ],col=mese, geom=c("smooth"), span=0.5)

plot.tav1 + layer(geom="point", size=4) + 
   scale_colour_gradient("stadio", low="blue", high="white", na.value = "grey50")
```

This is my code to represent the curve, and the error appears when I add the last part of "`scale_colour_gradient`".

Comment: `mese` is a factor (i.e. discrete value). you need to use a different color scale (scale_color_manual) and specify the colors you want to use that way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
set.seed(1492)

# make some similar data
tab1a <- data.frame(
  mese=sample(LETTERS[1:11], 84, replace=TRUE),
  taglia=runif(84, 50, 70),
  igs=runif(84, 5, 10))

tab1a_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue"))(11)

gg <- ggplot(data=tab1a, aes(x=taglia, y=igs, color=mese))
gg <- gg + geom_smooth(span=0.5)
gg <- gg + geom_point(size=4)
gg <- gg + scale_color_manual(name="stadio", values=tabla_colors)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```